# Objective-C wait for response after NSURLAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

I'm new to objective C. I'm creating a mobile version of a website that requires a log in. I am trying to figure out how to allow a username and password to be passed in after a NSURLAuthenticationChallenge is received. Here is my code:

Session.m

```
// log in
-(BOOL)logIn
{
    if (([Password class] == [NSNull class]) || ([Password length] == 0))
        return NO;

    if (([Username class] == [NSNull class]) || ([Username length] == 0))
        return NO;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_CONSTANT]
                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    if (!connection)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return Connected;
}

// handle authentiaction challenge
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"received auth challenge");
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"received auth challenge");
        NSURLCredential *credentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:Username
                                                                 password:Password
                                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to auth challenge");
    }
    else
    {
        Connected = NO;
        NSLog(@"previous auth failure");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Data received");
    Connected = YES;
}
```

Username and password are both being passed into a Session object from a UITextField. The problem here is that NO is being returned before the connection gets data. How can I tell the logIn method to wait for credentials to be passed in and then wait for a response if the credentials are valid?

Answer (score 0):

Advice:

- If possible, go iOS7-only.
- Once you do that, you should prefer shiny, new `NSURLSession`, which supercedes `NSURLConnection`. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW1) is a good place to get started.
- Many also like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).